# C# .NET Plugin Framework

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, prism, mef

I have been working on a Plugin based application in C#. Stumbled across Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) but this seems to be obsolete and support is dropped off Prism and other Frameworks.

Are there any alternatives to MEF for .NET Framework? A lot of information around plugins is rather dated and old.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MEF is NOT a Dependency Injection Container and for that reason it has been removed. So where to look?

- The Unity Container (not to be confused with the Unity game development framework), has long been a very popular container for Prism developers, and is what Brian has used for years.
- DryIoc has been a very popular and extremely fast alternative for the last several years and has converted many long term Unity fans because of it's performance and great API's.
- Ninject is still supported for the moment for WPF. That said this could change in the future. The project is showing signs of being dead. They haven't had a release in over 2 years, it's not particularly fast, or widely used by Prism Developers.
- BYOC (Bring your own container)... Prism 7 introduced a complete abstraction for Dependency Injection. This means that if there is a container that you would like to use, you can implement the IContainerExtension for the container you want and bring that into your project. **NOTE** for WPF development you would still need to tie that container into the ServiceLocator currently used by WPF. You can read more on that from this blog post on [Using "Unsupported" DI Containers](https://dansiegel.net/post/2018/10/29/using-unsupported-di-containers-with-prism)

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around a DI container and a plugin framework. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any alternatives to MEF for .NET Framework?

MEF is perfectly fine as *plugin framework*, no need to look somewhere else.

But you shouldn't *also* use it as dependency injection container (see Dan's answer).

Comment: There hasn't been an update to MEF since 2017 so I was worried to invest in it.

Comment: Why update something that's working as expected? People seem to be obsessed with updates these days...

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the insight.